# UserWarning: marker is redundantly defined by the 'marker' keyword argument when using plot_date function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using

```
plt.plot_date([dates[index], dates[index]+timeD], [pivots[index],pivots[index]], linestyle = "-", linewidth=2, marker = ",", )
```

to draw some lines on a chart.
This used to work, but now after doing some upgrades, a warning is displayed:

```
UserWarning: marker is redundantly defined by the 'marker' keyword argument and the fmt string "o" (-> marker='o'). The keyword argument will take precedence.
plt.plot_date([dates[index], dates[index]+timeD], [pivots[index],pivots[index]], linestyle = "-", linewidth=2, marker = ",", )
```

If I just omit marker = "," , the warning disappears, but there are two dots at the beginning and end of the line which I don't like.

What could I do to get rid of the warning without changing the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`plt.plot_date`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html) takes the keyword argument `fmt`, which is the matplotlib's shorthand for defining the marker and linestyle.

If you do not provide that `fmt` kwarg, a default value is used: `"o"`

One option option would be to use `fmt` to define both your marker and linestyle, instead of using the `marker` and `linestyle` kwargs:

```
plt.plot_date([dates[index], dates[index]+timeD], [pivots[index],pivots[index]],
              fmt=",-", linewidth=2)
```

---

For more info on `fmt`, see the Notes at the bottom the docs for [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html); note that it appears that `fmt` is used slightly differently for `plot_date` and `plot`, in that it is always defined for `plot_date`, while it is optional for `plot`.

---

As noted by @TomJohnson in comments, if you want a custom linestyle you can't use the `fmt` kwarg. One option here is to use `fmt` to define *only* the colour, and then use the `linestyle` and `marker` kwargs to define the rest of your desired format:

For example, instead of:

```
plt.plot_date(x, y, color='red', linestyle=(0, (5, 5)), marker=None)
```

Try using this, and the warning should go away:

```
plt.plot_date(x, y, fmt='r', linestyle=(0, (5, 5)), marker=None)
```